# Why does this javascript while loop hang?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, freeze

I was trying a very simple thing with javascript, to create a minesweeper grid.

```js
gridsize=9;

//grid initialisation 
var grid=Array(gridsize).fill(Array(gridsize).fill(null));

// this comes from  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range>
function randint(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

nbombs=20;
insertedbombs=0;

while (insertedbombs<nbombs){
    rx=randint(0,gridsize-1);
    ry=randint(0,gridsize-1);
    if (grid[rx][ry] == null){
        insertedbombs++;
        grid[rx][ry]='b';
    }
}
```

The while loop hangs, both in Chrome and Firefox consoles, all the values of the grid are filled, not just 20, i've no idea why, i guess i have some wrong understanding of javascript language, because the same code in python works.

Working python code:

```py
grid= [[None for i in range(9)]for i in range(9)]

nbombs=20;
insertedbombs=0;
while (insertedbombs< nbombs):
    rx=random.randint(0,8)
    ry=random.randint(0,8)
    if (grid[rx][ry]== None):
            grid[rx][ry]='b'
            insertedbombs+=1
```

Comment: `grid[rx][ry]` will never be `null`.

Comment: Your `grid` array contains the same inner array 9 times. If you manage to insert 9 bombs, then there are no spaces left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is that `Array#fill` doesn't do what you think it does.

In your example you create a SINGLE array `Array(gridsize).fill(null)` and then you put that array at each index of the outer array. Meaning that your `grid` actually contains the same array, 9 times over. So when you assign `grid[0][0]` you actually assign `grid[0][0]`, `grid[1][0]`, `grid[2][0]`, `grid[3][0]`, etc... all at once (ish).

```js
const gridSize = 9;

//grid initialisation 
const grid = Array(gridSize).fill(Array(gridSize).fill(null));

console.log(grid[0] === grid[1]);

grid[0][0] = 10;

console.log(grid[0][0], grid[0][0] === grid[1][0]);
```

What you want to do, is first fill the array with some dummy value, like `null`. Then map over the array and replace each entry with its own copy of `Array(gridsize).fill(null)`.

```js
const gridSize = 9;

//grid initialisation 
const grid = Array(gridSize)
  .fill(null)
  .map(() => Array(gridSize)
    .fill(null)
  );

const randInt = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

const nbombs = 20;
let insertedbombs = 0;

while (insertedbombs < nbombs){
    const rx = randInt(0, gridSize - 1);
    const ry = randInt(0, gridSize - 1);
    if (grid[rx][ry] === null){
        insertedbombs += 1;
        grid[rx][ry] = 'b';
    }
}

console.log(grid);
```

Comment: Thank you! So the problem was in the grid initialisation.